# Get height of each rows of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Is there any way by which I can get row height of each row in a `UITableView`. I have a `UITableView` which contains data which is dynamic, and I am using

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

to make dynamic row heights.

But I want to change height of overall `UITableView` as well, for that I need height of all the rows after reload of data.

I tried using

```
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.tableViewHeightContraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
```

But due to unknown reason it is giving me height less than what exactly it has, after I add 3 or 4 records in `UITableView` so thinking of other way around. To calculate height of each rows and then summing them up.

I am doing in Xcode 7.2, iOS 9 and Swift 2

Comment: Did you try to get cell rect like `CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: could you help me with this code in swift?

Comment: I am new at swift but I guess this will work. `let rect = self.tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)`

Answer (score 2):

```
var dictionaryOfCellHeight = [Int : CGFloat]()
var dataArray = [String]()
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {


    if dictionaryOfCellHeight[indexPath.row] == nil
    {
    var frame : CGRect = tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        if indexPath.row == dataArray.count
        {

            dictionaryOfCellHeight[indexPath.row] = frame.size.height
            //calculate total height and reload table
        }
        else
        {
        dictionaryOfCellHeight[indexPath.row] = frame.size.height
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: On executing this I am getting error in `if dictionaryOfCellHeight[indexPath.row] == nil` . Error is = warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

Comment: call the code in cellforRow if you want , and the purpose of 'dictionaryOfCellHeight[indexPath.row] == nil ' is to check for duplicate key. The key is indexpath.row which should be unique. I have not tested the code

Comment: Tried that too, in cellForRow error does not come but app freezes and memory footprint of app keeps on increasing and goes beyond 2 GB and table never loads up

Answer (score 1):

in Swift 3.0

let myRowHeight = yourTableView.rowHeight

Answer (score 0):

To change the height of `Tableview` , you don't need to calculate the height of all `UITableViewCell`s and set to `TableView`.
Set the `height` of each `UITableViewCell` properly in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method. This will automatically set the scrollable height to your `Tableview`

Comment: Scroll is working fine. But I dont want scroll to happen. That is why trying to change height of `UITableView`

Comment: Whats the purpose of adding tableview if you don't want to have a scroll effect ?

Comment: Repeating same design for multiple records and doing some action on click on them.

Comment: @Abhi If you just want to prevent scrolling, why not use [scrollEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollEnabled)?

Comment: @0x7fffffff in that also, I need to define height of my `UITableView` else some records might never become visible

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
CGRect frame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"row height : %f", frame.size.height);
```

Using `frame.size.height` you can get height of particular row

Answer (score 0):

This is because `self.tableView.contentSize.height` returns number of rows * `estimatedRowHeight`, which is not equivalent to actual height of the table view. What you need is to get the individual cell heights through `visibleCells`, then sum those up to get the table view's height.

Refer to this for the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40081129/4076956

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the table is not resizing its content, so if you try using `[self. tableView layoutSubviews];` to force the resizing, it may work. `[self. tableView layoutIfNeeded];` not necessarily forces the update.

Answer (score 0):

#### Functionally (one-liner)

NOTE: my section array stores the rows in the .data var

```
let heightOfAllRows:CGFloat = sections.enumerated().map { arg -> [(section:Int,row:Int)] in
            return arg.element.data.indices.map{ i in
                (section:arg.offset,row:i)
            }
        }.flatMap{$0}.reduce(0){
            return $0 + self.tableView(self, heightForRowAt: .init(row: $1.row, section: $1.section))
        }
```